# Email delivery and/or read reports

Tags: android, email

Android app can get a response on SMS sending. Is is possible to get email delivery and/or email read reports (responses)?

I cannot seem to find this in devs docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Far As I Know there is nothing that returns back the information to ActivityResult which can state wheather the Email was send correctly or user canceled or saved as draft.

Though I have never try to find out more in detail.

So my answer is NO